# Issue in drupal menus

Tags: menu, drupal-7

My main menu is appearing through print theme function but its sub menu is not appearing..What php code is written in template.php and then in page.tpl.php to get sub menus. I am trying for two days but no positive output.

Answer (score 0):

If by sub-menu you mean a secondary menu on a particular page; 
create the menu in **structure >> menus >> Add Menu** and add your links. Then go to **structure >> blocks** and find the block that corresponds to your menu and set it to appear on the relevant page and position within your theme.

If you want to add it within the .tpl file you can try something like this;

```
  <nav class="header__secondary-menu" id="secondary-menu" role="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
      'links' => $secondary_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanku tnum for your reply but i meant for the children of menu. I got the them from following code in template.php.        function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {$main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'); $variables['main_menu_expanded'] = menu_tree_output($main_menu_tree);

} then in page.tpl.php